# Javascript simple slideshowm, fadeIn?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why the fade is not function? I need to do simple slider with `fadeIn`. Can you help me?

```
function animace() {
    obrazky = ['img/xxx.jpg', 'img/xxx_1.jpg', '3.png'];
    if (obr + 1 == obrazky.length) obr = 0;
    else obr++;
    obrazek.src = obrazky[obr].fadeIn('slow');
    window.setTimeout('animace()', cas);
}
```

Comment: Take a look :http://jsfiddle.net/S4SmM/4/

Comment: `obrazky` is an array, not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

Even though jQuery is not tagged in your question, I am assuming it is jQuery's `fadeIn` method you are talking about.

`obrazky` is an array, not a jQuery object.

If you want to use the same image element and add an animation to it, you will need to something like this.

```
function animace() {
    obrazky = ['img/xxx.jpg','img/xxx_1.jpg','3.png'];

    if (obr + 1 == obrazky.length) {
        obr = 0;
    } else {
        obr++;
    }

    // obrazek is the jQuery object
    obrazek.fadeOut('slow', function(){
        this.src = obrazky[obr];
    }).fadeIn('slow');

    window.setTimeout('animace()',cas);
}
```

Comment: @user3615592 `This` being the above code, or `this` the context?